# filter out rows which satisfy a condition in each column

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a tensor:

```
input: ([[-0.5535,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000],
        [-1.1370, -0.2736],
        [-1.2300,  0.9185]])

Output:([[-0.5535,  0.0000],
        [-1.1370, -0.2736],
        [-1.2300,  0.9185]])
```

I need to keep only the rows which have non-zero elements in all columns, and the index of the deleted row. For simplicity, I have limited the matrix to two columns, however in my case the number of columns and rows keeps changing in every iteration.

I have found solutions where the condition may satisfy any element in the matrix, or there may be separate conditions to satisfy per column, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this particular case.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "keep only the rows which have non-zero elements in *all* columns" or "keep only the rows which have non-zero elements in *at least one* column"? The first row in your example satisfies the latter but not the former.

Comment: @GoodDeeds "keep only the rows which have non-zero elements in all columns" - this is what I am looking for. The first row in my example needs to stay in the output because not all columns are zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[4,5,6]])
mask = x!=0
index = mask.prod(axis=1).astype(bool)
x[index.astype(bool),:]
```

The idea is to identify which values are different from zero, then multiply across the columns, change to boolean, and use that as an index to your array. I did this with Numpy, but I guess the idea is similar with Pytorch

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question since I found the solution in pytorch.

This function will return the row-indices of non-zero elements:

```
x[torch.nonzero(torch.tensor(x), as_tuple=True)[0].unique()]
```

OR

```
x[torch.nonzero(torch.tensor(x.sum(1)), as_tuple=True)[0]]
```